# Joins and where conditions

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have the following (shortened query):

```
SELECT 
    `Statistics`.`StatisticID`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `Flags`.`FlagType`) AS `FlagCount`
FROM `Statistics`
LEFT JOIN `Flags` ON `Statistics`.`StatisticID` = `Flags`.`StatisticID`
WHERE `FlagCount` = 0
GROUP BY `Statistics`.`StatisticID`
ORDER BY `SubmittedTime` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Now, neither `FlagCount = 0` or `COUNT(Flags.FlagType)` work in the `WHERE` clause. I thought about using a `SET` but I'm not sure how I'd add that to the query. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try subquerying if HAVING doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    `Statistics`.`StatisticID`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `Flags`.`FlagType`) AS `FlagCount`
FROM `Statistics`
    LEFT JOIN `Flags` ON `Statistics`.`StatisticID` = `Flags`.`StatisticID`
WHERE `Statistics`.`StatisticID`
  IN (SELECT `Flags`.`StatisticID` 
      FROM `Flags`
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Flags`.`FlagType`) <= 3
      GROUP BY `Flags`.`StatisticID`
  )
GROUP BY `Statistics`.`StatisticID`
ORDER BY `SubmittedTime` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I think this is getting to the right approach - except it returns result that only have greater than or 3 flags. I'll play around with it.

Comment: I removed the GROUP BY in the sub-select and changed IN to NOT IN and it seems to work. The main reason HAVING doesn't work is because it doesn't seem to support gt/lt values (or I'm doing something strange). HAVING should work in most cases though.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Flags.FlagType) = 0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Ah this only works with = 0 - is there a way to make it work with <= 3 for example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `Statistics`.`StatisticID`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `Flags`.`FlagType`) AS `FlagCount`
FROM `Statistics`
LEFT JOIN `Flags` ON `Statistics`.`StatisticID` = `Flags`.`StatisticID`
                     And `FlagCount` = 0
GROUP BY `Statistics`.`StatisticID`
ORDER BY `SubmittedTime` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

@eed3si9n

This partially works - however I need it to be <= 3 which doesn't seem to work.

Also the `HAVING` clause is executed last which won't return as many results as I need (as set by `LIMIT`). Is there a way I can do this in a `WHERE` clause instead?

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried, and say how it doesn't work.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html: "The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)"